# Creating global variable yml/ini to access from controllers

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create my own **site_globals.yml(or ini)** file under `app/config/` and access its variables from any controller. How do I do it?

**app/config/site_globals.yml(or ini)**

```
globals:
    name: Symfony
    middle: Master
    surname: To Be
```

**Note:** I know how to access parameters of parameter.yml file in controllers with `$this->container->getParameter('xxxxxxxx')` but I want to create my own file.

I tried as this blog ([Symfony 2: Using Global Variables](http://www.dinduks.com/symfony-2-using-global-variables/)) shows but got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the article and the Symfony 2 documentation says:

```
# app/config/site_globals.yml
parameter:
  my_wonderful_global: xxx
  globals:
    name: Symfony
    middle: Master
    surname: To Be

# app/config/config.yml
imports:
  - { resource: parameters.yml }
  - { resource: security.yml   }
  - { resource: site_globals.yml   }

// In a controller action
$myWonderfulGlobal = $this->container->getParameter('my_wonderful_global');

// This will give you an array
$myGlobals = $this->container->getParameter('globals');

echo $myGlobals['name']; die();
```

Are you trying to do something different?

Comment: Doing exactly same thing but keep getting this error: `FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "/var/www/html/local/sport/app/config/site_globals.yml" from "/var/www/html/local/sport/app/config/config.yml". (There is no extension able to load the configuration for "my_wonderful_global" (in /var/www/html/local/sport/app/config/site_globals.yml). Looked for namespace "my_wonderful_global", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "football_team", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution")`

Comment: Parameters key was missing in custom yml file.